# My turtle fell from fifth floor, almost 40 ft

Tags: turtles

[image][image]

I kept it at the window side for basking and it jumped off. When I went down it was walking, but was bleeding near the mouth. Now, I keep it in water and it looks like bleeding has stopped. It is moving normally, no cracks are visible in the shell (hoping there is no crack), but it's not taking food or opening its mouth. Is there anything to worry about; any internal injury or jaw fracture? I am posting the pics from when it was bleeding, and afterwards when keeping it in water. Is it safe to keep it in water or should I keep it dry to prevent infection? It's one year old, no vets nearby.

Comment: If you're having trouble finding vets, I'd look for area animal rescue and rehabilitation groups. They'll usually have a wildlife vet they use to care for injured animals they take in. Or if you call other groups that deal with wild animals, like zoos or game wardens, they would probably be able to recommend a vet in the area.

Comment: 40 ft is a big fall and bleeding from the mouth could indicate internal injuries.  Good luck.   A vet would able to tell you more and hopefully treat the injuries.

Answer (score 1):

**TAKE IT TO THE VET OR ANIMAL HOSPITAL!!!** Your turtle might be seriously injured. If someone broke their leg, would you say "alright time to go swimming now!" Even better example, your friend falls off that window, so you take him out for food and than go swimming. It's the same with turtles. You take them to the vet/hospital.